# How to create a scoped version of ext-all-gray.css?

Tags: extjs4, sass, compass-sass

Looks like latest version of ExtJS doesn't come with a scoped version of the gray theme. How to use SASS and Compass to generate a scoped version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The accepted answer is not answering the question.

To get a scoped version the gray theme:

1. install [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)
2. Then, on command line, move to the ExtJs Sass folder e.g. `/extjs/resources/sass`
3. duplicate the file `ext-all-gray.scss`
4. add the line `$scope-reset-css: true;` at the top of the file.

Then run: `compass compile ext-all-gray-scoped.scss`

This will create a file `ext-all-gray-scoped.css` in the CSS folder which you can now use.

Comment: +1 for having provided the process step by step! Here is how to install compass on windows : http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/70417/#Comment_70417

Comment: Hi :) I found a bug in IE7 caused by `ext-all[-gray].css` and I need some help to fix it. Could you take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311480/how-to-fix-scoped-css-for-ie)?